# Android text file not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a text file in my solution called "txtWords.txt", which I attempt to read with:

`string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);`

`string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "txtWords.txt");`

In my experimenting, I've got the same file under both my C# App and the App.Android > Assets folder (set to AndroidAsset). I thought to put it in both locations to be safe.

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.WSC/files/txtWords.txt"`

I've read about using AssetManager but that gives me a "namespace could not be found error".

What am I doing wrong and what's the best way to read a text file for an app? This should be really easy so I'm doing something fairly basic wrong, I suppose.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a PCL/NetStd (Xamarin.Forms) library or an Xamarin.Android library

Comment: a file in your solution is NOT contained in the personal folders, it will be embedded in the app bundle.  For Android, the best way to accomplish what you want is to use an Asset

Comment: Are there any good examples of how to use Assets? I've tried but can't understand how to use the Asset namespace correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xamarin Essentials you can read a bundled/asset read-only file via your NetStd (Xamarin.Forms) library:

```
string wordsText;
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("txtWords.txt"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var wordsText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?tabs=android

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the answer. Although weirdly I'm now getting the "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method" error even though OpenAppPackFileAsync is being used. That's a separate issue to investigate!